# My Company uses Cognito for authentication. I need to write Lambda triggers that write into DynamoDB. What aws permissions do I need?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-cognito

My Company uses AWS Cognito for authentication. Due to a use case requiring me to disable user login after x number of invalid login attempts, I need to write Lambda triggers that write into DynamoDB. I would like to know what should I ask from my Company, *What AWS permissions do I need on my username (that I use to login to AWS console)* ?.

Comment: What does the dynamodb have to do with cognito? What does you user(name) have to do with the lambda?

Comment: If you are asking what permissions you need to deploy a lambda that then does this task: a lot of permissions. There is no easy way to find it out other than to actually run the deployment and then add each permission incrementally until the deployment works. E.g. do you need S3 access to upload the lambda code, do you need KMS access, do you need IAM access to create a role for the lambda, do you need permission to set up something that triggers the lambda, ...

Comment: yes incremental development could be an option, I would like to see if someone else has knowledge about what access do I need. I prefer to ask my company for all types of access in one go rather than incremental

Comment: If you are a developer you should have full access to the account anyway and basically be able to do anything (action * on resource *), maybe except networking setup since that is something on the org level (explicit deny). If you need to ask for specific fine-grained AWS permissions be prepared to spend a couple of days for the smallest of tasks.